# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_9 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (80, 2048)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I am currently trying to build a working lstm model in Keras that receives an Embedding from a CNN that comes before the RNN. The CNN shows the expected behavior but I'm not 100% sure if I can just pass the Embedding from the CNN to the RNN.

```
def model_builder(input_shape):
    base_input = Input(shape = input_shape)
    x = LSTM(units=1, name='LSTM1', return_sequences=True)(base_input)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(units = 2)(x)
    x = Activation('softmax')(x)
    classification_model = Model(base_input, x,name='classifier')
    classification_model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

    return classification_model

embedding_model = build_model((256, 256, 3))
classification_model = model_builder((2048,1,))

try:
    image_embedding = embedding_model.predict(X)

    outcome = classification_model.fit(x=image_embedding, y=Y, batch_size=10, epochs=20, verbose=1, 
              callbacks=None, validation_split=0.5, validation_data=None, shuffle=False, 
              class_weight=None,sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=None, 
              validation_steps=None, validation_freq=1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

When I run the training like this though, I get this Error Message:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusting the code like this solved it for me. The problem was that I needed to add a time dimension to my embedding that I was passing through my lstm. So basically going from (batch_size,input_dimension) to (batch_size,input_dimension,timesteps). The order of those dimensions might not be correct. I still need to check that, but this solution should at least get the model to work.

```
image_embedding = embedding_model.predict(X)
new_image_embedding = image_embedding[:,:,np.newaxis]

outcome = classification_model.fit(x=new_image_embedding, y=Y, batch_size=batch_size, 
          epochs=epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_split=0.5,  
          validation_data=None, shuffle=False, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None, 
          initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=None, validation_steps=None, 
          validation_freq=1)
```